# What is the etymology of the phrase "Holy Trinity"?

Tags: etymology

I recently typed up an answer here on the network, and made use of the phrase "Holy Trinity".  I did so in an ironic, non-religious (and hopefully non-offensive!) context, knowing *vaguely* what the phrase means and where the phrase comes from.

However, I've never *really* figured out where that phrase comes from.

[I ***very well*** now understand](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2049) that this particular phrase never **specifically** occurs in the Bible; instead, it is used as shorthand to refer to "The Father, The Son, and The Holy Spirit" when discussing this[ese] [three] entity[ies] in scripture.

But, if this phrase was never in the Bible to begin with, how did it come about?

Note that I'm not particularly interested in a specific religious answer on this one, but simply the etymology of this phrase.  If it *did* so happen to come out of a religious institution, I'd like to know which one.

Comment: This is really a question, either for the Christianity site, or for the History site. But I would suggest you look at the Nicene Creed (325CE) and all that followed from it as containing the principal clue to your question. [This site](http://peopleof.oureverydaylife.com/did-nicene-creed-lead-break-between-roman-catholic-greek-orthodox-9190.html)may help.

Comment: @WS2:  Both of those have got some pretty strong leads.  Thanks for that.  If there are some more concrete pieces of evidence in there, I may wind up answering this one.

Comment: Are you asking about the **etymology** (*Trinity* is fairly obviously related to *three*; *holy* comes from German *heilig*) or the **history** (When the Holy Trinity was first called that; who coined the phrase)?

Comment: @Andrew **etymology** 2.
a chronological account of the birth and development of a particular word or element of a word, often delineating its spread from one language to another and its evolving changes in form and meaning. {[Dictionary.com Unabridged
Based on the Random House Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/etymology)}

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That definition is really unhelpful in ascertaining what the OP is actually asking for. The term *Trinity* was originally coined **in Latin** in 415 on the Algerian coast.

Comment: I was addressing your assumption that everyone has to use / understand the meaning you choose for 'etymology'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives a  straightforward summary of the etymology of *trinity*:

> **Trinity** n {M[iddle] E[nglish] *trinite*, fr. A[nglo-]F[rench] *trinité*, fr. L[ate] L[atin] *trinitat*-, *trinitas* state of being threefold, fr. L[atin] *trinus* threefold} (13c) 1 : the unity of Father, Son, and Holy Spirit as three persons in one Godhead according to Christian dogma} ...

What this summary tells you is that the word *Trinity* appeared in English from Middle English in the thirteenth century; that it was derived ultimately from the Latin word for "threefold," and that its original meaning in English was the religious one indicating the three-in-oneness of Jesus/God/Holy Ghost.

The earliest instance that a Google Books search for "Holy Trinity" turns up is from [*Articles agreed upon by the Bishops, and other Learned and Godly Men, in the last Convocation at London, in the year of our Lord 1552. To root out the Discord of Opinions, and establish the Agreement of TRUE RELIGION. Published By the Kings Majesties Authority, 1553.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O_BYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22holy+trinity%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHgbb76_LOAhUDKiYKHTipCXwQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22holy%20trinity%22&f=false) (1553):

> *Of Faith in the **Holy Trinity**.*
>
> There is but one living and true God, and he is everlasting, without body, parts, or passions; of infinite power, wisdom, and goodness, the Maker and Preserver of all things both visible and invisible. And in unity of his God-head there be three persons, of one substance, power and eternity, the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost.

The king was Edward VI, in what proved to be the final year of his reign.

---

***Update: A look at early matches for 'Trinite' and an earliest match for 'holy Trinite'***

In hopes of finding an earlier instance of "Holy Trinity," I ran a Google Books search for *Trinite*, the predecessor word in Middle English to *Trinity*. The most interesting result was a concordance to the A, B, and C versions of William Langland, [*William's Vision of Piers Ploughman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Plowman), the famous medieval allegorical poem, which Wikipedia reports was written circa 1370–1390.

The concordance turns up several dozen matches for *Trinite* [or *trinite*], and it finds even more matches for *holy* (particularly in the combinations *holy chirche* [or *churche* or *kyrke* or *kirke*], *holy gost* [or *goste* or *goost*], and *holy writ*, but also occasionally in the forms *holy day* [or *dayes* or *daies*], *holy men*, and (once each) *holy Seintes* and *holy euen*. But there is only is only one instance in which *holy* and *Trinite* appear in the same line, and in that case *holy* modifies *goost*:

> So grace of þe holy goost þe grete myȝl of þe Trinite

Virtually all instances of *Trinite* in *Piers Ploughman* are preceded by *þe*. This proves nothing about whether some contemporaries of William Langland used the term *holy Trinite*; but it does provide fairly strong evidence that in the late 1300s *holy Trinite* was not a set phrase in Langland's part of England the way that *holy chirche*, *holy gost*, and *holy writ* were.

In Tarjei Park, "[Reflecting Christ: The Role of the Flesh in Walter Hilton and Julian of Norwich](https://books.google.com/books?id=ucfbRfBFf-MC&pg=PA87&dq=%22trinite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKpu3Y6fPOAhUE7mMKHfItD0w4FBDoAQhMMAg#v=onepage&q=%22trinite%22&f=false)," in *The Medieval Mystical Tradition in England: Exeter Symposium V* (1992), the academic author reproduces several quotations from Julian of Norwich's *Revelations of Divine Love* (ca. 1395), including one that comes close to "holy Trinity":

> For the **Trinite** is God, God is the **Trinite**; the **Trinite** is our maker and keeper, the **Trinite** is our everlasting lover, everlasting ioy and blisse, be our lord Iesus Christ. And this was sewed in the first and in all; for where Iesus appereith the **blissid Trinite** is understood, as to my sight.

Most of Julian's mentions of *Trinite* are unmodified, but the last one, *blissid Trinite*, comes close to *holy Trinite*. Still her choice of *blissid* in place of *holy* as the adjective suggests that "holy Trinite" was not a set phrase in her own mind.

An 1841 edition of [*Lyttleton, His Treatise of Tenures, in French and English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_1i_opjDyWoC&pg=PR35&dq=%22trinite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKpu3Y6fPOAhUE7mMKHfItD0w4FBDoAQhFMAc#v=onepage&q=%22trinite%22&f=false) includes in its introduction the text of Thomas Lyttleton's will (written not later than 1481), which includes this provision:

> Also I bequeth my gode littel mass book and gode vestment with the apparel to an auter of the same sorte of vestments which were my moder's, and also a gilt chalës, I geve them to the **blessed Trinitë**, to the use and occupation of my chapel of Frankley in honour of our said most **blessyd Trinitë**: inasmuch as the said chapel of the **blessyd Trinitë** and an aulter thereof is halowed in the worship of the said **blessyd Trinitë**, for to have masse songen there on **Trinitë Sunday** and other high festivals and other days to the pleasure and honour of our said most **blessyd Trinitë**.

This is Julian of Norwich's preferred phrase with a vengeance (especially as Lyttleton charges that the Lord of Frankley must meet the terms of this bequest and obligation "as he will answer to the blessed Trinitë").

However, a search of the Early English Text Society's collection, [*Songs, Carols, and Other Miscellaneous Poems, from the Balliol Ms. 354, Richard Hill's Commonplace-book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JSVLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22trinite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKpu3Y6fPOAhUE7mMKHfItD0w4FBDoAQgqMAI#v=onepage&q=%22holy%22&f=false) (1907), whose contents Hill gradually collected over the period 1508–1536, finds one crucial match. Searches within the book yield 43 pages matches for *holy* and 12 pages with matches for *Trinite* [or *trinite* or Trynite]—and one pair is in combination:

> **Vnto the Trinite.**
>
> **Holy Trynite**, blessed & eterne,
>
> Ever regnyng *in* p*ar*fight vnite,
>
> Whose power, Lord, no thynk may deserne,
>
> Ne þe joyes no*m*bre of thy dignite,
>
> Thy grace eu*er* in eche necessite
>
> Be my ocowr, my fawt*is* to redresse,
>
> & w*i*t*h* thyn hond, Lord, eu*er*y day me blesse!

Google Books is very poor and finding matches from before the late 1500s, owing to the relative scarcity of early books in its database and to OCR problems with early English fonts. So there are surely some and perhaps many earlier instances of *Holy Trinity* in published English than the earliest one it finds (from no later than 1536). But there is at least some reason to doubt that *Holy Trinity* was already in widespread use in England as *holy Trinite* in the late medieval period, as well as some reason to suppose that during the period 1390–1490 the wording *blessed* [or *blissid*] *Trinite* may have been in more common use.

Comment: You might find the [Athanasian Creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed) is a bit earlier than 1550, although that was originally written in Latin, of course. It was probably translated into English earlier than the 1553 Prayer Book, though. And that creed is founded on Augustine's *De Trinitas* (also Latin) published in 415. The doctrine is ancient.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Andrew, I think you need to make that an answer.

Comment: I'm humbled by the effort you put into this particular answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Note that the poster's question is about the exact phrase "Holy Trinity," not the word _Trinity_ by itself or in other combinations. Nevertheless, I have expanded my answer to cover research into Google Books matches for "trinite" (the predecessor word in English to _trinity_) and for instances of the specific phrase "holy Trinite."

Answer (score 4):

The concept of unity of "The Father, The Son, and The Holy Spirit" was adopted in 381 by [Constantinople council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Constantinople). In the minutes of the council, you may read:

> "Haec enim **sancta Trinitas** unus est Deus, Pater et Filius et Spiritus
>   Sanctus, ...".

*I don't know when "sancta Trinitas" (Holy trinity) was first translated in English*.

Answer (score 4):

The **Trinity** as a word entered Middle English in the 13th century, and was associated with *Holy* and similar words from the start. **Holy Trinity** would first appear uninterrupted around 1300.

The [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED47107/track?counter=1&search_id=1750352) entry cites an early instance from about 1250 as written in a manuscript of the *Ancrene Riwle*, a guidebook for [anchoresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorite) (or female anchorites):

> Tu ʒette me ham, **holi þrumnesse, trinite** [Pep: Trinete], iþe wurðschipe of þe.
>
> You get me home, **holy Three-ness, Trinity**, in the worship of you. (rough translation - unsure about first *tu* and distrusting of *iþe*)

The use in the *Ancrene Riwle* is remarkable because some of the first attempts to write clerical rules in Middle English were for women pursuing spiritual devotion, including anchoresses. The *Ancrene Riwle*, the texts of the *Katherine Group*, and other writings were explicitly addressed to women audiences. Despite the interruption of an earlier word for *Trinity* (*thrumness* or three-ness), the close coincidence of *holi* and *trinite* show the words are already associated.

**ETA** and here the phrase appears in the closely-related [Ancrene Wisse](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/hasenfrantz-ancrene-wisse-part-three), dated by the editor Robert Hasenfratz to be from 1225-1240:

> Ther **the Hali Trinite** - "thrumnesse" on Englisch - schawde hire al to him: the Feader in his stevene, the Hali Gast i culvre heow, the Sune in his honden. (Part 3, lines 464-466)
>
> There **the Holy Trinity** - "threeness" in English - showed herself completely to him: the Father in his voice, the Holy Spirit in the dove's shape, the Son in his hands. (editor's translation)

Around 1275, the usage appears again in the medieval (and fanciful) chronicle of British history, *[The Brut](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/LayCal/1:148?rgn=div1;view=fulltext)*:

> Anan he gon to wurche ane swiðe feire chirche a **seinte Trinetðes nome**. (lines 14739-40)
>
> Anon, he goes to build an exceedingly fair church in the **holy Trinity's name**.

This part of the narrative describes the actions of [King AEthelbert of Kent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86thelberht_of_Kent) , converted by St. Augustine of Canterbury at the start of the 7th century. *Seinte* functions as an adjective that means something like *holy* or *sacred*.

Finally, by 1300 the appelation appears in a form close to our own Holy Trinity in the *[South English Legendary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AHA2708.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext)*, a collection of saint's lives:

> Lo here..gret bi-tokningue of **þe holie trinite**, Of fader and sone and holie gost bi þeose ʒeorde þreo. (233-4)
>
> See here ... a great sign of **the Holy Trinity**, of Father and Son and Holy Spirit by these three a garden. (Rough translation)

From this time, the word appears much more widely and consistently, in ways documented by Sven Yargs's answer.

Comment: 'Thrumness'. _Must_ be sound.

Comment: *Thrum* is a great word. A crowd is a *thrum*. A majestic multitude is a *thrum*. *Thrumness* may be a pun. Incidentally, OED gives an earlier usage that I might edit in: "c1175   Lamb. Hom. 99   He scal ileafan on **þa halȝa þreomnesse** and on soðre annesse."

Comment: I came across it in 'Dragonsinger' (McCaffrey).

Comment: If Makoto comes back, I hope that he switches the accepted answer to this one. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

They were seriously nailing this down circa A.D. 500. Check out the precision of the wording in the [Athanasian Creed](https://carm.org/athanasian-creed-500-ad).

Comment: Hello, Steve. One assumes that Paul was as clear as humanly possible on the _doctrine_ of the Tri-unity, but the question here is when the word 'Trinity' (which you'll see I think is lopsided) entered the English language. Graffito makes this distinction (but doesn't address what is actually being asked, either).